# Android - AdjustResize won't work with external library that extends FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I use an external library called `DragListView` [here](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView). This `DragListView` extends a `FrameLayout` and it contains a `RecyclerView` inside. The structure is like:

```
DragListView extends FrameLayout {
     RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
}
```

The items populated into RecyclerView contains an `EditText`. With the `EditText` near the top of the screen (which is not covered if the soft keyboard appears) works just fine. But the one which is covered by the soft keyboard will gain focus then lose focus at once when called `myEditText.requestFocus();` then the keyboard covers that `EditText`.

Here is the layout of my activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ui.activities.ChecklistsActivity">

<include layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"/>

<com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_checklists"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

`android:layout_gravity="top"` works for me once with my old structure where the DragListView is a nested child inside a `RecyclerView` (I set the top gravity for the `RecyclerView`), but it's not working anymore in this case.

I cannot use `AdjustPan` because it will push my action bar away (but it works, sadly). Mine app is not in fullscreen (still able to see the status bar, I assume it's not fullscreen, correct me if I'm wrong please). I tried a few things but nothing work.

I called `myEditText.setFocusable(true);` and `myEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` just before `myEditText.requestFocus();`.

I put `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` for the `DragListView` or the root `LinearLayout`.

I tried different ways of calling the keyboard to popup like

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

or with a KeyboardUtils which received the Activity for `getCurrentFocus();`

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And one more thing just in case. I don't know if there's anything related to my "custom" keyboard with `edtSubItemName.setImeActionLabel("Done", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);` because I want a multiline `EditText` with "Done" action key. The xml of the `EditText` item is here:

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/edit_text_sub_checklist_item"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/height_checklist_setting"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/height_checklist_setting"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:imeOptions="actionDone"
       android:maxLength="256"
       android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_default"
       android:visibility="invisible" />
```

The `android:visibility="invisible"` is because there's a button to press to make it visible.

I'm getting mad with it for a few days. Was I missing something? Feel free to ask for more information.

Thank you all for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` for the layout manager before setting `myDragListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

The list then start at the last item, so I just call `myDragListView.scrollToPosition(0);` after `setAdapter` to make it back to the top like normal. The interesting thing is that the position of the items is still the same (still from top to bottom) so there's nothing much to do.

Hope this helps someone.